# Castor Mapping: How to map a <![CDATA[ tag

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, castor

I have a XML file and I need to extract the info in `"<![CDATA["` tag using Castor in spring-mvc. I need to know how to write the mapping.xml file.

Here is the XML:

```
    <comprobante>
     <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <comprobanteRetencion id="comprobante" version="1.0.0">
      ****
      </comprobanteRetencion>
     ]]>
    </comprobante>
```

Comment: I removed the tag. Here is the solution: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306682/org-xml-sax-saxexception-illegal-text-data-found-as-child-of/33043205#33043205)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the tag CDATA. Once I removed that tag, I could treat the xml file normally. Here is the whole [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306682/org-xml-sax-saxexception-illegal-text-data-found-as-child-of/33043205#33043205)

Answer (score 1):

Only you can know what the "info" in this XML is. As far as the XML parser and schema are concerned, your XML fragment is precisely equivalent to

```
<comprobante>
     &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
      &lt;comprobanteRetencion id="comprobante" version="1.0.0"&gt;
      ****
      &lt;/comprobanteRetencion&gt;

    </comprobante>
```

That is, the CDATA tag is just a way of saying "don't treat angle brackets in here as markup".

Comment: Then, it means that I can't map or extract the content in CDATA tag?

Comment: I don't know whether Castor provides any workaround, but in general, I would not expect tools to provide mechanisms that treat CDATA as something that has structural semantics, because the consensus in the XML world is that it does not.